# ORACLE get rows with condition value equals something but not equals to anything else

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have rows that look like .

```
OrderNo     OrderStatus     SomeOtherColumn
```

---

```
A               1               
A               1 
A               3 
B               1                X
B               1                Y
C               2
C               3 
D               2
```

I want to return all orders that have only one possible value of orderstatus. For e.g Here order B has only order status 1 SO result should be

B 1 X
B 1 Y

Notes:

1. Rows can be duplicated with same order status. For e.g. B here.
2. I am interested in the order having a very peculiar status for e.g. 1 here and not having any other status. So if B had a status of 3 at any point of time it is disqualified.

Comment: Shouldn't the output here be B and D?

Comment: No. Because i want that very particular order status which in this case is 1 and not 2.

Comment: Seems there is a confusion as to what i really want. I will add more examples to my question hoping that it clarifies what i really want.

Comment: Can `orderstatus` be `NULL`? If so, would it be considered distinct from whatever input you give (such as 1 in your example)? In other words: what if in your example for `orderno = 'B'` you had order status 1 in one row and NULL in the other - would you still want to select the rows with `odrerno = 'B'`? Or does a NULL orderstatus automatically disqualify the order? (Or - perhaps - status can never be NULL?)

Comment: good question. Orderstatus is not a nullable field. SO cant be null.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t.orderno = t2.orderno and t.OrderStatus = t2.OrderStatus
                 );
```

If you just want the orders where this is true, you can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select orderno
from t
group by orderno
having min(OrderStatus) = max(OrderStatus);
```

If you only want a status of 1 then add `max(OrderStatus) = 1` to the `having` clause.

Comment: Wow. Thx for the min max idea. I had over simplified my original problem but the min max idea will give me an optimized query while solving my problem.

Comment: @thePoly_glot - You make absolutely no sense. In a Comment below your question, you said you only want the order numbers that have a **specific** order status, such as 1. (You only want B in the output, you don't want D.) Gordon's answer does exactly what the other poster asked you: it returns both B and D - the order numbers that each has exactly one order status. Please make up your mind, and either comment here telling Gordon what you really need, or respond again below your question to the other Comment.

Comment: @mathguy edited my question. Let me know if it still confusing.

Comment: @thePoly_glot - Did I **edit your question**? I don't think so. **You** edited your own question, in response to a question I asked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. It does not handle the case where the status can be NULL; if that is possible, you will need to explain how you want it handled.

```
SQL> create table test_data  ( orderno, status, othercol ) as (
  2      select 'A', 1, null from dual union all
  3      select 'A', 1, null from dual union all
  4      select 'A', 3, null from dual union all
  5      select 'B', 1, 'X'  from dual union all
  6      select 'B', 1, 'Y'  from dual union all
  7      select 'C', 2, null from dual union all
  8      select 'C', 3, null from dual union all
  9      select 'D', 2, null from dual
 10  );

Table created.

SQL> variable input_status number
SQL> exec :input_status := 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> column orderno format a8
SQL> column othercol format a8

SQL> select orderno, status, othercol
  2  from   (
  3           select t.*, count(distinct status) over (partition by orderno) as cnt
  4           from   test_data t
  5         )
  6  where  status = :input_status
  7    and  cnt    = 1
  8  ;

ORDERNO      STATUS OTHERCOL
-------- ---------- --------
B                 1 X
B                 1 Y
```

One way to handle NULL status (if that may happen), if in that case the `orderno` should be rejected (not included in the output), is to define the `cnt` differently:

```
count(case when status != :input_status or status is null then 1 end) 
      over (partition by orderno) as cnt
```

and in the outer query change the WHERE clause to a single condition,

```
where cnt = 0
```

Comment: is this better than performing a self join and then filtering out .not a relational db expert.

Comment: @thePoly_glot - Not an IT professional myself, either. But... From what I read, analytic functions (like the `count() over (...)` as used here) were introduced PRECISELY in order to avoid self-joins, for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

[Count](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions032.htm) distinct `OrderStatus` partitioned by `OrderNo` and show only rows where number equals one:

```
select OrderNo, OrderStatus, SomeOtherColumn 
  from ( select t.*, count(distinct orderstatus) over (partition by orderno) cnt 
           from t )
  where cnt = 1
```

**<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/692f8/1)</sup>**

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add something to Gordon's answer, using a stats function:

```
select orderno
from t
group by orderno
having variance(orderstatus) = 0;
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. MIN and MAX are very easy to calculate. VARIANCE is a much more complex calculation (especially when multiple values are present). I view this as "subtracting" something from Gordon's answer, rather than adding to it.

Comment: I realize MIN and MAX are easier concepts to understand, but that doesn't mean they're easier to calculate - they're still O(n), same as VARIANCE. In fact, as far as I can tell, they use the same execution plan. I just tested on a table with 3M rows, and running either query first caches the other one.

Comment: I agree that Gordon's answer is better, for being easier to understand. I just though this was neat.

Comment: The execution plan will not show calculations done by the CPU. (If you show CPU usage you may see the difference.) VARIANCE may be O(n), but with a greater coefficient - 5n is five times more than n, even though they are both O(n). The variance is computed by keeping a running sum of values and a running sum of the square of values (and a few more operations at the end). So for each row: two additions and a multiplication. Min and Max each require just an inequality comparison for each row. Addition and especially multiplication are more expensive than inequality comparison.

Comment: Okay, but *testing if the variance is 0* is an easy optimization that requires no multiplication or addition - you just return false if any of the values aren't equal. I'm fairly sure that Oracle does something like this; the query used 2% more CPU than MIN+MAX when I tested, but ~50% more CPU if it's changed to `variance(col) > 0.1`.

Comment: Fair enough, but I should say, I am really impressed if this is indeed an optimization the folks at Oracle thought about. Good to know!

Comment: Will this not return D with orderstatus 2

Comment: @thePoly_glot nope, I wrote it before you updated your question. But mathguy's answer should solve your problem.